# Register button not reacting when TextFields are full

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm making a sign up screen, it's connected to Firebase Authentication. The problem is when all the TextFields are fullfield the "Register" button doesn't react, but when they are empty it reacts correctly with the toast message I have put.The button is linked correcty to the xml file. Here is my code:

```
class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)
        var signinlinkbtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.signin_link_btn)

        signinlinkbtn.setOnClickListener { startActivity(Intent(this, SignInActivity::class.java)) }

        var signupbtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.signup_btn)

        signupbtn.setOnClickListener {
            CreateAccount()
        }

    }

    private fun CreateAccount() {
        var fullNameSign = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.fullname_signup)
        var usernameSign = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username_signup)
        var emailSign = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.email_signup)
        var passwordSign = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password_signup)

        val fullName = fullNameSign.text.toString()
        val userName = usernameSign.text.toString()
        val email = emailSign.text.toString()
        val password = passwordSign.text.toString()


        when {
            TextUtils.isEmpty(fullName) -> Toast.makeText(this, "This field is mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(userName) -> Toast.makeText(this, "This field is mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(email) -> Toast.makeText(this, "This field is mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(password) -> Toast.makeText(this, "This field is mandatory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            else -> {
                val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this@SignUpActivity)
                progressDialog.setTitle("SignUp")
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please, wait!")



                val mAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful)
                        {
                        saveUserInfo(fullName, userName, password, progressDialog)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            val message = task.exception!!.toString()
                            Toast.makeText(this, " $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            mAuth.signOut()
                            progressDialog.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

    }

    private fun saveUserInfo(fullName: String, userName: String, password: String, progressDialog: ProgressDialog) {
        val currentUserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val userRef: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

        val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
        userMap["uid"] = currentUserID
        userMap["fullname"] = currentUserID
        userMap["username"] = currentUserID
        userMap["email"] = currentUserID
        

        userRef.child(currentUserID).setValue(userMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if(task.isSuccessful)
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The account is created successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    val intent = Intent(this@SignUpActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                }
                else
                {
                    val message = task.exception!!.toString()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "$message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                }
            }

    }
}
```

It worked before and the users data were going to the Auth table in Firebase but suddenly it stopped. If someone has any idea what went wrongg, I'd be glad to know.

Comment: I don't the issue in your code at first glance, nut since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).